# Display multiple PHP query results in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

So have the following while loop which will output all the results for a SQL query carried out in PHP:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $restaurant_name = $row['restaurant_name'];
    $cusine = $row['cusine'];
    $wait_time = $row['wait_time'];
    $output = "Resturant Name: $restaurant_name <br /> Cusine: $cusine <br /> Average Wait Time: $wait_time";
    echo "$output";
}
```

You can assume that `$result` will contain the table which I am reading on row at a time. The above code is working just fine but when I try to display the information in HTML (so that it actually looks nice) I run into a problem

If I do the following:

```
<html>              
<section id="main" class="container 75%">

    <header>
        <h2>Here Are Some Places You'd Like To Eat</h2>
    </header>

    <div class="box">
    <?php echo $output; ?>
    </div>
</section>
</html>
```

It will only display the very last resort. I know that this happening because `$output` can only hold one string at a time, but I don't know any other way to display the information on the HTML. I though of possibly using an array to store all the strings, but the documentation doesn't show me how to set-up a dynamic array.

Does anyone here know how to display all the results of the search query in an HTML page?

Comment: You should just generate the HTML while you're going through the while loop.  Otherwise, you'll have to dump the lot of it into an array.  Then loop through the array to generate your HTML.

Comment: You could collect all data in a array and iterate over this data-array in a foreach loop. every loop generates the single data for every restaurant

Comment: @durbnpoisn That's exactly what I'm trying to figure out. I tried to put the while loop inside of the HTML file but it wouldn't display the results properly. I don't usually program in HTML or PHP so I'm not used to this whole cosmetic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do combine both php and html code like this:

```
<header>
    <h2>Here Are Some Places You'd Like To Eat</h2>
</header>

<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) :
    $restaurant_name = $row['restaurant_name'];
    $cusine = $row['cusine'];
    $wait_time = $row['wait_time'];
    $output = "Resturant Name: $restaurant_name <br /> Cusine: $cusine <br /> Average Wait Time: $wait_time";
    echo "<div class=\"box\">$output</div>";
endwhile;
?>
```

This way you don't have to use an array to display the result.

Comment: Wow it even breaks them into separate little boxes with the information! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: to avoid backslash escaping you can also write: echo '<div class="box">' . $output . '</div>';

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
    <h2>Here Are Some Places You'd Like To Eat</h2>
</header>

<div class="box">
<?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
    echo 'Restaurant name: '.$row['restaurant_name'];
    echo 'Cusine: '.$row['cusine'];
    // ...and so on
  }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this gonna work for more than one entry in the result of the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the loop produce the HTML inside your div with a table. I am not sure what your CSS is like for your `box` class, but this will certainly make it look better while printing out all of your results.

```
<header>
  <h2>Here Are Some Places You'd Like To Eat</h2>
</header>
    <div class="box">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Restaurant</td>
          <td>Cusine</td>
          <td>Wait Time</td>
        </tr>
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
        $restaurant_name = $row['restaurant_name'];
        $cusine = $row['cusine'];
        $wait_time = $row['wait_time'];

        echo "<tr><td>". $restaurant_name . "</td><td>" . $cusine . "</td><td>" . $wait_time . "</td></tr>"; 
      }
     </table>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your $output variable every loop, and then trying to echo $output later; it will only contain the data from the last iteration.

Instead, make $output an array containing your data and then loop over it for display purposes:

```
$output=array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) :
    $output[]=$row;
endwhile
```

Then you can loop over the $output array to build an output for each restaurant:

```
foreach($output as $value):
    $returnDetails='<div class="box">';
    $returnDetails.='Resturant Name: '.$output['restaurant_name'].'<br />';
    // etc. for all details
    $returnDetails.='</div>';
    echo $returnDetails; 
endforeach;
```

Added benefit of this way: you have access to the $output array if you ever wanted to access a single row outside the context of the loop